# I can not understand how this method works?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I can not understand how this method works:

```
public DrawingCanvas(int[][] pixels, int rows, int cols){
    image = new BufferedImage(cols, rows, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    int pixel = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
        int col = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++){                 
            if(c+11 < cols){
                pixel = pixels[r][c+11];
            }
            else{
                pixel = pixels[r][col];
                col++;
            }
            image.setRGB(c, r, ((255<<24) | (pixel << 16) | (pixel << 8) | pixel)); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking if you understand how this method works?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: it is executed... there is a cpu and a stack and stuff...

Comment: I mean what do this method ?

Comment: what do you think it does???  start there...

Comment: The method changes the color of an image pixel by pixel. Period.

Comment: Also, it's a constructor.

Comment: it's a bad place for that code.

Comment: @TMcKeown it depends on the design. We cannot be sure if it's misplaced or not.

Comment: typically you would call another method instead of doing it in the ctor, I will say it's not a good practice to do what it is doing.

Comment: Sorry for the question, i'm not professional in Java.

Comment: @Eric you don't need to be a professional in Java, just have a basic notion on algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

This method is scanning image (stored in image object of BufferedImage ) using the for loop and changing the color pixel by pixel by using `setRGB` method

Comment: Thank you for your answer and a special thanks for all who down votes the question...